# reduction of order method $xy''+2y'-xy=-e^x$ ,$y_1=\frac{e^x}{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Reduction of order method

$$xy''+2y'-xy=-e^x$$

being

$$y_1=\frac{e^x}{x}$$

a solution of the associated homogeneous differential equation.

I have followed the method and i came to

$$y=-\frac{e^x}{2}+c_1e^x+c_2\frac{e^x}{x}$$

instead of the correct answer

$$y=-\frac{e^x}{2}+c_2\frac{e^x}{x}+c_1\frac{e^{-x}}{x}$$

The equation I obtained after making

$$y=u\cdot\frac{e^x}{x}$$

was:

$$-1=u''+2u'$$

Was the error before that or after?

Thanks

Comment: $e^x$ does not satisfy the homogeneous equation $xy^{\prime \prime} + 2y^\prime - xy = 0$ but $e^{-x} \over x$  does.

Comment: the question says $y_1=\frac{e^x}{x}$ satisfy the homogeneous equation, not $y_1=e^x$

Comment: both $e^{-x} \over x$ and $e^x \over x$ are solutions of the  homogeneous equation.

Comment: @abel would you mind to see if you arrive to $-1=u''+2u'$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y = {ue^x \over x}$ or $xy = ue^x$ differentiating both sides twice you get $$xy^\prime + y = (u^\prime + u)e^x,  xy^{\prime \prime} + 2y^\prime =(u^{\prime \prime} + 2u^\prime + u)e^x $$ therefore 
$$ xy^{\prime \prime} + 2y^\prime -xy =(u^{\prime \prime} + 2u^\prime + u)e^x -ue^x = (u^{\prime \prime} + 2u^\prime)e^x = -e^x$$  so $u$ satisfies $$ u^{\prime \prime} + 2u^\prime = -1$$ which has solutions $$u = -{x \over 2} + A + Be^{-2x}, 
y = -{e^x \over 2} + A{e^x \over x} + B{e^{-x} \over x} \text{ where $A,B$ are arbitrary constants. } $$

Comment: can you see the question <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089199/construct-a-complete-3rd-order-ode-with-constants-coefficients-knowing-2-particu> please? Thanks

Comment: @LDLD, i posted an answer. let me know if you can follow what i am doing there. do you have any prelims coming up?

Comment: i am a student of mechanical engineering and i am gonna have an exame of my last maths subject this week

Comment: @LDLD, good luck on your exam.

Comment: thanks again for being so kind! if i have another doubts can i ask you?

Comment: @LDLD, yes, please do. if it is not too hard i will try to answer it.

Comment: would you mind to see the question <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090336/diferential-equation-system-differential-operators-method>? thanks